# App_GlobalResources .resx files taking time after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

we have modules where we are uploading ***.resx*** file through file uploader but after upload, our web form website getting hanged up for some time no one able to access the site at that movement.

please tell me the reason for the same and is there any resolution for the same.

Comment: Do you upload to the directory, that contains the web files? Then asp.net thinks it's part of the application and recompiles everything. Upload to a folder outside your web, if you don't want that.

Comment: But if i uploaded in different folder how i can use it into application

Comment: App_GlobalResources contains files, that must be compiled. So your server will recompile everything when that content changes.

Comment: Is there any solution u can provide which will help me to avoid locking to applications

Comment: If you want to update files without recompilation, you should not use '.resx'. You can for instance use JSON files (they don't get compiled).

Comment: You could also use a database (sql) to store your data.